# Alternator isn't charging battery properly. Replace or swap regulator only?

Tags: honda, electrical, alternator, fit

I have a 2015 Honda Fit EX. On my dashboard, there is a small screen that has been displaying "CHECK CHARGE SYSTEM" and displaying warning lights (TPMS, power steering, and stability control).

I took it in to a mechanic and they diagnosed it as a bad alternator that isn't charging the battery fully.

The alternator itself sounds fine (still quiet) and only has 50k miles on it, so I believe the bearings and the internals are still good.

Can I just change the regulator in this instance? When should you swap the regulator versus swapping the entire alternator?

Comment: Its strange to have the alternator fail at such low mileage. Do you know if they do a proper battery load test?

Comment: Shouldn't it be still covered under warranty? Either way, you don't know if the regulator needs to be swapped. A diagnosis is required.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing Not under warranty (it ended on that at 36k). I can't believe it failed that early either.

Comment: @racefever By battery load test, is that the test where they check the voltage and the CCA output? They did test the battery separately and it looked fine (CCA exceeds spec, voltage is normal).

I'll be doing a voltage drop test later today, as well as pulling the battery and having it tested elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, and thats a good plan of action!

Comment: Well I am actually stumped and will probably open a new question soon. The alternator seems to be working just fine now and the light hasn't appeared since then. Hm.

Comment: @KevinEvans: Could be you just had some corrosion on a connector, and your testing shifted things around enough to get around it. If so, your problem will probably come back in a few months. If it does, I'd recommend cleaning both your battery terminals and the alternator output lead connection, and reassembling everything with some dielectric grease to keep things clean going forward.

Comment: What other warning lights were being displayed? The alternator isn't the only thing that can illuminate the battery light.

Comment: @Ben TPMS, powersteering, and stability control

Comment: I don't know how easy it is to remove the alternator on your car, but if it's easy, you should pull it off and take it to a local alternator shop. They'll usually test it for free and sell you a rebuilt one for a good price if you need it ($55 for me).

Comment: A 1 year car with 50k should be warranty-Take it to a dealer maybe there is a recall. You can check online on Honda website using your vehicles VIN #

Comment: check the field coil connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a regulator fault. I sell these alternators daily, and we cannot get the regulator as a spare part (well, not here in NZ, anyway).

The alternator has a feedback terminal to the ECU. If it does it again, give the alternator connector a clean and see if it goes away. If it does, the issue is a loose connection. If it doesn't, then the issue is internal and you're up for a new unit.

The reason the other lights come on, is that the ECU recognizes that these items may fail if the battery is not fully charged. As the report is not coming back from the alternator to say that it *is* charged, the ECU flags a fault on those items as well.

Of course, the above assumes that the battery is in good condition. As the car is less than a year old, it would be pretty odd if the battery is faulty. 
A proper load test and off-vehicle charge should clear the battery of guilt.

> When should you swap the regulator versus swapping the entire alternator?

When you know what has damaged the regulator in the first place and it has been fixed. If, for instance, the rotor has a short circuit and is drawing too high a current, the new regulator will fail also.

When it is a major job to extract the alternator for repair. If it's a 3 hour workshop job to get the unit out, you don't want to do that twice. I believe the Honda is not that hard, so it's really a call to be made from your wallet ;)